# Checkbox and radiobutton in same row with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Its my beginning with Twitter Bootstrap so that question might be quite silly, but I've no idea how to solve that issue. I want to put checkbox and radiobutton in same row (should be displayed vertically aligned) but checkboxes and radiobuttons should be grouped in two separated fieldsets. I've got something like that:    [html snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/ycj8ndge/) 
but checkboxes are displayed higher than radiobuttons and putting them in the same div doesn't change anything.

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>
                     <h6>RB:</h6>

                </legend>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>
                     <h6>CB:</h6>

                </legend>
                <div class="row">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: something like [that](http://jsfiddle.net/ycj8ndge/1/) ?

Comment: Nope, I want 1 checkbox and 1 radiobutton in row and then skip to new row. http://snag.gy/kxT7s.jpg

Comment: try this http://plnkr.co/edit/GQIR88ZPfXC4AG6ebjIW?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>
              <h3>RB:</h3>
            </legend>

            <div class="radio">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
            </div>

            <div class="radio">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 2</label>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>
              <h3>CB:</h3>
            </legend>

            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="">Option 1</label>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="">Option 2</label>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**[Have a look at the JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m5yyrre2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could use the inline form class [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline)

or you could wrap your checkbox inputs with the checkbox class like this:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```